# How to take away the 'execute' permission from the root user?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm asked to take away the permission for the root user to execute a bash script, is that even possible? Actually how would one take away any permissions from some user? with `chmod` I could modify it for the current logged in user, but not for root.

Comment: It'll screw everything up, but `chmod -x /bin/chmod`

Comment: @OleksandrKravchuk wouldn't I lose the ability to use chmod? Also it's more of a homework style question, so really it wouldn't matter if he could get it back. EDIT: LMAO no thanks

Comment: yes, you would.

Comment: glad I didn't try that huuuh

Comment: The root user by definition has complete control over the user space of a Linux environment. There are things that can be done to make a root user's life more difficult but the user will have the power to overcome any controls.  Taking Oleksandr's example, a root user could create a new file with execute permissions, take an image of the chmod command without execute permission outputting it to the new file and hey presto, a new file with execute permissions that does the same job as chmod.

Comment: so yes the correct answer is that it useless to do, should I perhaps then delete the question?

Comment: I think you could fix the non-executable `chmod` problem by running something like `install 755 /bin/chmod /bin/new_chmod`, then using the new copy to fix the permissions.

Comment: @chepner Relevant https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83862/how-to-chmod-without-usr-bin-chmod

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are simply looking for a small safeguard, an *obstacle* to accidentally running the script as `root`, write the script to voluntarily exit if run as root. Add the following to the beginning of the script:

```
if [[ $EUID == 0 ]]; then
    printf 'Do not run this script as root\n' >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that, root can do everything. But there are some measures to make it difficult. You can use the following command in ext{2-4} filesystems:

`chattr +i script.sh`

Doing this the file can't be modified, but it can be unlocked using `chattr -i script.sh`

Other thing you can do is: Put the script you want unchangeable for root on remote server and mount it via NFS. If the server does not offer write permissions that locks out the local root account. Of course the local root account could just copy the files over locally, unmount the remote stuff, put the copy in place and change that.

You cannot lock out root from deleting your files. If you cannot trust your root to keep files intact, you are having a social problem, not a technical one.